# Can't change settings for Mobile Broadband Dongle - Button is greyed out

Tags: broadband

I was with VirginBroadband.com.au (Australia).  My huawai 3G Dongle was working great on Ubuntu, However I have changed ISP's.

I unlocked the modem, and put in the new SIM.  I have tested this in my Windows PC and it connects to the new (Optus) Network A-OK and it all works.

When I put this dongle (the same one that was working fine in Ubuntu) into that same Ubuntu Netbook it simply won't connect.

When I try to go into the dialog to try and add or change settings the button to change or update settings is greyed out, I can't select it.  Apparently since this dongle was already recognized the Broadband Setup Wizard won't start, and I have no idea how to get it to start (presuming it has the ability to configure an already recognized dongle).

What do I have to do to either enable the ability to change the configuration for this setup, or to blow away the one that is set up so the Broadband Wizard will re-start and let me configure a new one.

Can anyone provide simple instructions for doing this?  I'm using Ubuntu with the Cinnamon Desktop

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to create new network connection setting for the same dongle? Both settings co-exist and you can connect any one of them. If the new connection works and you can edit it then just delete the old non-editable one.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch the GUI connection manager by running the following command in Terminal

nm-connection-editor

Once the window appears, select the connection you want to edit by clicking on the "*" (settings) symbol.